# Bootstrap hover image display example

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to display a simple image when user hovers over link, im following the [example found here](http://embed.plnkr.co/nhlFPz) to the letter,but im not getting any image displayed.

I have the following UI, when user clicks view fleet the data gets returned asynchronously, and the example code is placed within the script returning the data, thus:

[image]

**User Clicks View Fleet**

[image]

**CODE**

```
$('a[rel=popover]').popover({
  html: true,
  trigger: 'hover',
  placement: 'bottom',
  content: function(){return '<img src="'+$(this).data('img') + '" />';}
});
```

**ViewFleet.php**

```
<td> <a class="btn" rel="popover" data-img="//placehold.it/400x200"> <?php echo $row['model']  ?></a></td>
```

Any help or advice on the above much appreciated.

Comment: did you include tooltip plugin?

Comment: @monkeyinsight I did not...let me check quicky

Comment: @monkeyinsight sorry if im being stupid here but I cant see the tooltip plugin...

Comment: Popovers require the tooltip plugin to be included in your version of Bootstrap.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console ? @TimothyCoetzee

Comment: @SathvikCheela negative...no errors, I believe @monkeyyinsight is on the right track but I am unsure how to enable tooltips, according to docs this code should do it  `$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})`

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee I think there is no need to enable tooltip. All you need to do is include bootstrap css and js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is working :

- add bootstrap  and jquery
- add http: at the begging of the    image url incase you are
  testing without server ( just open the file at the browser ) without http request

> ```
> <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
> <a class="btn" rel="popover" data-img="https://placehold.it/400x200"> ABC TEST </a>
> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
>
>
> <script>
> $('a[rel=popover]').popover({
> html: true,
> trigger: 'hover',
> placement: 'bottom',
> content: function(){return '<img src="'+$(this).data('img') + '" />';}
> });
> </script>
> ```

Comment: Thank you had to make a small tweak, but got it working

Answer (score 2):

Try this code instead that will help you to show an image on hover:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement : 'top',
        trigger : 'hover',
        html : true,
        content : '<div class="media"><a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="image2.png" class="media-object" alt="Sample Image"></a><div class="media-body"></div></div>'
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 200px 150px 0;
    }
    .bs-example button{
        margin: 10px;
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover">Popover with image</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```